# Spark streaming maxRate is violated sometimes

Tags: configuration, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I have a simple Spark Streaming process (1.6.1) which receives data from Azure Event Hub. I am experimenting with `back pressure` and `maxRate` settings. This is my configuration:

```
spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true
spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate = 900
spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate = 1000
```

I use two `receivers`, therefor per microbatch I would expect 2000 messages (in total). Most of the time this works fine (the total event count is below or equal the `maxRate` value). However sometimes I have spikes which violate the `maxRate` value.

My test case is as follows:

```
- send 10k events to azure event hub
- mock job/cluster downtime (no streaming job is running) 60sec delay
- start streaming job
- process events and assert events number smaller or equal to 2000
```

In that test I can observe that the total number of events sometime is higher than 2000, for example: 2075, 2530, 2040. It is not significantly higher and the processing is not time consuming however I would still expect the total number of events per microbatch to obey the `maxRate` value. Furthermore sometime the total number of events is smaller than `backpressure.pid.minRate`, for example: 811, 631.

Am I doing something wrong?